# Change color of text box when start typing in it rather than click

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am working on a site where I am creating a form and validating it with `JavaScript`. Everything is going well but I have an issue.

When a user leaves a field empty and clicks on the submit button, the form shows an error, changes the color of the text box, and the cursor is automatically focused on that field.

However, I want that when the user starts typing in the field the color of the field automatically turns back to its default state. I want this work to be done in `JavaScript`. Please help me I am not getting any logic for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `onkeydown()` instead of `onclick()` event.

Answer (score 0):

This code may work:

```
This code may work:

<textarea id="txtId" onkeydown="changeColor()"></textarea>
<script>
  function changeColor(){
    document.querySelector("#txtId").style.backgroundColor="defaultcoloryouwant";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can we do it using id or name? Actually I am new in javascript

Comment: Yes you can if your id's name is txtId you just have to replace the 'textarea' in document.querySelector("textarea")    with #txtId.  I.e document.querySelector("#txtId");

Comment: Edit:I have added the code to deal with a specific Id

Comment: Its a great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
var textinput= document.getElementById("textinput");

textinput.onchange = function() {

    if(textinput.value == "")
    {
        textinput.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    else
    {
       textinput.style.backgroundColor = "green"; 
    }
};
```

Comment: this works only when enter is pressed and if there is already some text. not when all key is pressed down.

Comment: Yes, it's true. It was just a sample for suggest the right way. Thank you for making it clear.

Comment: maybe it would works using onkeydown instead of onchange.